# What is the grammatical structure: "The dog licked the dish clean."

Tags: word-order, syntax, parts-of-speech, transitivity

> The dog licked the dish clean.

Which rules of grammar does it follow?

Can I interpret the sentence like **'The dish got clean due to dog's licking of the dish'** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume this is about the placement of the adjective "clean".  Some verbs allow for an object complement to indicate the effect of the action. You may see

> rub it smooth

The adjective gives the effect of the rubbing.  Note this is different from "rub it smoothly" which describes the action of the rubbing, not the effect.

Your example is the same, so your interpretation is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are correct. The structure is subject+verb+object+adjective. Here are some more examples:

1. You made me happy
2. We wring the clothes dry.

This is called **object complement**

Merriam Webster defines objective complement as

> a noun, adjective, or pronoun used in the predicate as complement to a verb and as qualifier of its direct object (such as chairman in "we elected him chairman")

For further reading: [What Is an Object Complement? (with Examples)](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/object_complement.htm)